# Initial Color is not being set properly (Swift UI)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the `Color` library from Swift UI as a part of my View's state. I'm trying to set my view's color when I initialize it, but the Color isn't being set correctly.

Here is my code:

```
struct CalcButtonView: View {
    var calcButton: CalcButton
    var highlightAble: Bool = false
    @State var foregroundColor: Color? = nil
    @State var backgroundColor: Color? = nil
    @State private var highlighted: Bool = false

    @EnvironmentObject var numObservable: NumObservable

    init(newCalcButton: CalcButton){

        /// Buttons that are light gray
        let lightGrayButtons: [String] = ["C", "+/-", "%"]
        /// Buttons that are orange
        let orangeButtons: [String] = ["/", "x", "-", "+", "="]

        self.calcButton = newCalcButton
        self.highlighted = false
        self.foregroundColor = Color.white
        if lightGrayButtons.contains(self.calcButton.label){
            self.backgroundColor = Color.lightGray
            self.highlightAble = false
        } else if orangeButtons.contains(self.calcButton.label){
            self.backgroundColor = Color.orange
            self.highlightAble = true
        } else {
            self.backgroundColor = Color.darkGray
            self.highlightAble = false
        }
    }

}
```

The result is that all my background colors are back with my foreground color as blue, when my foreground is explicitly set to White while my background color is not supposed to be black.

I'm thinking this has something to do with my Color struct being set to `nil`. Thoughts?

As requested, here is my `body` implementation:

```
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.numObservable.updateOrOperationDelegate(buttonLabel: self.calcButton.label)
            self.toggleHighLight()
        }, label:{
            Text(calcButton.label)
                .background(self.backgroundColor)
                .foregroundColor(self.foregroundColor)
                .cornerRadius(75)
        })
    }
```

Update #2: Upon more testing, I found out that my variables `foregroundColor` and `backgroundColor` are still `nil` even after my `init` function runs. Does anyone know how that can be?

Comment: Can you show us your `body` implementation?

Comment: @Palle I added my body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution. I have an idea about why this works, but I don't know technically why it works. I think it has something to do with how Swift handles `@State`. The reason I **think** my original code doesn't work is because `@State` isn't ready to be set yet.

Once I moved my code outside of the initialization portion, it worked. Here is my code that achieves my original goal:

```
struct CalcButtonView: View {

    var calcButton: CalcButton
    var highlightAble: Bool
    @State var buttonForeground: Color = Color.white
    @State var buttonBackGround: Color?
    @State private var highlighted: Bool = false

    @EnvironmentObject var numObservable: NumObservable

    init(newCalcButton: CalcButton){
        let orangeButtons: [String] = ["/", "x", "-", "+", "="]

        self.highlightAble = false
        self.calcButton = newCalcButton
        self.highlighted = false
        if orangeButtons.contains(self.calcButton.label){
            self.highlightAble = true
        }

    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.numObservable.updateOrOperationDelegate(buttonLabel: self.calcButton.label)
            self.toggleHighLight()
        }, label:{
            Text(calcButton.label)
                .background(self.buttonBackGround)
                .foregroundColor(self.buttonForeground)
                .cornerRadius(75)
        }).onAppear {
            /// Buttons that are light gray
            let lightGrayButtons: [String] = ["C", "+/-", "%"]
            /// Buttons that are orange
            let orangeButtons: [String] = ["/", "x", "-", "+", "="]
            if lightGrayButtons.contains(self.calcButton.label){
                self.buttonBackGround = Color.lightGray
            } else if orangeButtons.contains(self.calcButton.label){
                self.buttonBackGround = Color.orange
            } else {
                self.buttonBackGround = Color.darkGray
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The changes are in the `.onAppear`portion. All I did was move my `background` and `foreground` logic to `.onAppear`. If anyone could tell me why this works then I'd appreciate it.